# reading a file using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, windows, csv

i am trying to read a csv file from my desktop using the code below but instead a get the subsequent error yet the path is correct. some kindly assist

```
Data= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/bryan/OneDrive/Desktop/Data for candidate.csv")
```

error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/bryan/OneDrive/Desktop/Data for candidate.csv'
```

i am trying to read a csv file but instead a get the subsequent error yet the path is correct. some kindly assist

```
Data= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/bryan/OneDrive/Desktop/Data for candidate.csv")
```

> error= FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:/Users/bryan/OneDrive/Desktop/Data for candidate.csv'

Comment: The error message is clear - no file was found at that path. The first step is for you to check that path. Are you running on windows? If you try `dir "C:/Users/bryan/OneDrive/Desktop/Data for candidate.csv"` on the command line, what happens?

Comment: Using a raw string as a path might help the situation. Put the letter `r` before the quote mark like `r"PATH"`. If this does not solve the problem check if the file exists.

Comment: @MSH - that would be a great suggestion if backslashes are in use, but not needed if its forward slashes only.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the file out of OneDrive. Sometimes it causes trouble. Save it in `user/<username>/Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the "Data for candidate.csv" file. Don't let space exist in the name. You can name it like this: "Data_for_candidate.csv"

Comment: No, spaces are allowed in file names. Depending on context, they may need to be escaped somehow. For instance, on the command line, where Windows will divide tokens at spaces, it would need to be escaped or quoted. But in this context where nothing is parsing the file name , its fine.